# latitude longitude of Address

Tags: bing-maps

I am finding the latitude and longitude of a Address `4760 matric Drive, winter park, FL, 32792` and bing map giving lat long `28.604771`, `-81.292976`. This same i am doing with my request from URL and the url is  `http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=USA&adminDistrict=FL&locality=&postalCode=32792&addressLine=4760%20matric%20Drive&key=Mykey&output=xml` 
This is response me the lat long

```
 <Latitude>28.610404968261719</Latitude>
 <Longitude>-81.2994155883789</Longitude>
```

Why the same address are different Lat Long from bing map. Please give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

Trying both forms of the address in the REST services I'm getting the exact same result which is the second set of coordinates you provided. The reason for this is that the geocoder matched the postal code and not the road.

The Bing Maps website returns the first result you mentioned but the website is using a completely new geocoder that is currently being tested before being used on the backend of the developer API's.